# String interpolation. Printing individual items of an String array

Tags: swift

I just started learning Swift by following the Apple documentation. Here is an example from documentation.

```
let names = ["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]
let count = names.count
for i in 0..<count {
    print("Person \(i + 1) is called \(names[i])")
}
// Person 1 is called Anna
// Person 2 is called Alex
// Person 3 is called Brian
// Person 4 is called Jack
```

I have query on printing statement. I dont get it that `\(names[i])`,
can somebody please explain?
I know string interpolation also some `(for in)` loop too when we loop through each item.

but I don't understand `\(names[i])`

Comment: The expressions `list[i]` means **the ith element in the list**. In other words, the program is looping over the indices of `names` and printing a message for each one, eg. "Person 1 is called Anna".

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use something like [enumerated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated), which gives you a sequence of (index, item) pairs.

Comment: It's described in the chapter *Collection Types* paragraph *Accessing and Modifying an Array*

Comment: I get that what program is doing but I want to know about that syntax it is use like string interpolation so. Actually I am really confuse

Comment: See *String Interpolation* in chapter *Strings and Characters*

Comment: (for i ) mean it will loop through everything like \(names[i])

Comment: i thought its only related to 0..<count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a number in brackets like this: names[3], it means you want the value in the names array from the 3rd position. Remember arrays start with 0 so the 3rd position would be the fourth number in the array list.

The i means you want the number in there to change for each loop. So the first time the loop runs it will run like names[0] and then the second time it runs it will run like names[1] and it will continue like this until the loop completes.

The \names[i] means your putting a variable in the middle of a string. So if you wanted to print a normal string you would use "this is a string" but if you wanted to print a string with a variable in the middle you could do this:

```
let variable = "long variable"

Print("this is a string with a \(variable)")
```

And it would print out: this is a string with a long variable

**EDIT**: if you want to print each value of array on separate line there are two ways to do it.

The first is:

```
For item in names
{
Print(item)
}
```

Or you can do:

```
For i in 0..<names.count
{
Print(names[i])
}
```

Comment: Yeah I understand what you saying about looping also the index of array.
Just clear me one thing.
for i in 0..<count  
means ( i ) will loop 0 to 3 and ( i ) only operate on 0..<count  
but ( i ) operating on array list too \(names[ i ])  
 \(names[ i ]) is this an syntax to print every single value of an array on a separate line?

Comment: @martheli-
The i means you want the number in there to change for each loop. So the first time the loop runs it will run like names[0] and then the second time it runs it will run like names[1] and it will continue like this until the loop completes.
this answer clear my confusion. ( i ) again doing same looping from 0 to 3 with list of array. like it did with 0..<count
right?

Comment: @Tanzz i is just a placeholder for the values. So as you loop through the array, i changes to the value of each loop. So first it will be 0, then 1, then 2 and so on until the loop finished. I added some more to my answer above.